# Fail to load API definition Swagger - Django rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui

I am completely new to DRF and Python need your help here
getting "Fail to load API definition" Swagger ERROR, while loading the Swagger page
using drf-yasg package

below are my configurations

note: app is the name of my Django Project and repertoire is the Django app

app\urls.py

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="BMAT API",
        default_version="v1",
        description="BMAT API v1",
        terms_of_service="",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="sivaperumal2000@gmail.com"),
    ),
    public=True,
    urlconf="app.urls",
)

urlpatterns = [
path(
    "",
    schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0),
    name="v1-schema-swagger-ui",
),
    path("repertoire/", include("repertoire.urls"))
]
```

Error MSG

```
    Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\views.py", line 94, in get
    schema = generator.get_schema(request, self.public)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\generators.py", line 242, in get_schema
    endpoints = self.get_endpoints(request)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\generators.py", line 311, in get_endpoints
    enumerator = self.endpoint_enumerator_class(self._gen.patterns, self._gen.urlconf, request=request)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\generators.py", line 30, in __init__
    super(EndpointEnumerator, self).__init__(patterns, urlconf)
  File "D:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\generators.py", line 65, in __init__
    urls = import_module(urlconf)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Comment: You've passed `urlconf="app.urls"` to `get_schema_view`, is the correct path for your root url conf?

Comment: Don't name an app as `app`

Answer (score -4):

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'DEFAULT_FIELD_INSPECTORS': [
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.CamelCaseJSONFilter',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.InlineSerializerInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.RelatedFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.ChoiceFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.FileFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.DictFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.SimpleFieldInspector',
        'drf_yasg.inspectors.StringDefaultFieldInspector',
    ],
}`enter code here`
```